# can't click to a div button selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```js
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
   withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).
   build();


driver.get('https://www.tumblr.com/login');
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('signup_email')).sendKeys('my_username');
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('signup_password')).sendKeys('my_password');
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('signup_forms_submit')).click();

driver.wait(function(){
driver.get('https://www.tumblr.com/search/love+gifs');
},5000);

driver.wait(function(){
  driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id("post_control like")).click();
},1000);

driver.wait(function(){
  driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id("follow-text")).click();
},1000);

driver.quit();
```

```html
<div class="post-info-post-tumblelog">
<div class="post-info-tumblelog">
<a class="follow_link worded-follow-button show-unfollow" data-subview="follow" href="/follow/pleasingpics" style="width: 41px;">
<div class="follow-text" title="Follow">Follow</div>
<div class="unfollow-text" title="Unfollow">Unfollow</div>
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

I have a Javascript code for following some accounts on Tumblr using Selenium WebDriver.

In the HTML code, there is a follow button as you can see in a class named "follow-text". But my code doesn't work, also I'm wondering that follow button is not actually a button but they've made it a clickable div class. I'm not so familiar with HTML/CSS and I'm new with Javascript and Selenium Webdriver. What's wrong with my code? Also I have to click follow buttons on different posts on the same page. I'm thinking of creating a loop but I can't even click one of them. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Not to be the buzzkill here, but pretty sure this would be violating Tumblr's T's & C's: ***"... or overloading the Services, or by scripted use of the Services in such a manner as to interfere with or create an undue burden on the Services."*** - 1 follow every second could be deemed spammy/a burden.

Comment: I don't know the terms & conditions but this is a part of my internship program, that's why I'm doing it because it's important for me. Time between actions could be longer than 1 sec but anyway, thank you for your comment.

Comment: If it's an internship, and they're asking you to do that either knowingly violating rules, or unknowingly - that's a bad sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
driver.wait(function(){
  var followButton = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/article[5]/header/div/div/div/a/div[1][@class='follow-text']"));
  followButton.click();
},1000);
```

This code solved my problem. I guess firebug's xpath selector gave the wrong answer to me. I changed it a lot and finally it worked. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to click on the parent element. Not on the div, but to the `<a>` -- as parent of div.

Comment: I've tried to click the part starting with <a class="...." but it didn't work either.           driver.wait(function(){
  driver.findElement(webdriver.By.className("follow_link worded-follow-button show-unfollow")).click();
},1000);

Comment: its because of Selenium dont work with compilations of classnames. you need to search by xpath or by "follow_link" only

Comment: @ÇağatayBarın did you fix the issiu?

Comment: nope, I'm trying different things like By.className or By.xpath or By.cssSelector but it's not working :(

Comment: @ÇağatayBarın  by class "follow_link" will work for you =) try it

Comment: I've fixed the problem by using xpath but another problem occurred to me. Now, I can click follow or love buttons but after clicking one of them whichever is first, program gives this error:   UnknownError: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (564, 726). Other element would receive the click: <div class="unfollow-text" title="Unfollow">...</div>   I guess the reason is that when it clicks to follow, follow button turns into unfollow button and this change cause a crash in code which i can't do another action :( How can I solve this one ? :D

Comment: @ÇağatayBarın easiest way is to click via javascript on this button. Element is not clickable means that its hidden by some other element visually or some similar problem. But if you doing this with js script -- its no matter.... But also possibly you need to click on some another element of webpage.

Comment: how I'm going to do that? I'm already coding in javascript, is there something else that I can run script in my code ? And yeah, I have to click many buttons in the same webpage.

Comment: oh, I was think that you working with selenium web-driver =) in this case I have no idea what is the problem if you tried to click via js

Comment: no no, I'm working with selenium webdriver but I guess what you mentioned is something else I don't know. I'm going to try that clicking with script.

Comment: if you already coding on js -- you working with selenium 1.0, but not with web-driver.